# Delete right row from a table model that is sorted differently than the table view

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.4

I have a QStandardItemModel and a QTableView. The view is sorted differently than the model. I am using a QSortFilterProxyModel.

If I select a row in the view that I want to delete, how do I know to which row in the model that corresponds to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From,

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html

> QModelIndexList QItemSelectionModel::selectedIndexes() const
>
> Returns a
>   list of all selected model item indexes. The list contains no
>   duplicates, and is not sorted.

This is accessible from the selection model of the view.

You also can determine which row in the view represents which QModelIndex. For Example `QAbstractItemView::visualRect(const QModelIndex &)` gets visual rect of an index. There is also `indexAt(const QPoint &)` to map in other direction.

And now since you added that you are using a proxy model, then use the proxy model's function to map to original model -- `QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource`

In summary,

1. get selection model and selected QModelIndex
2. map to original QModelIndex
3. delete in the original QStandardItemModel

Comment: Thanks, with mapToSource it works. Also, I am using currentIndex() instead of selectedIndexes().

Comment: Btw, I think the QPoint for indexAt is in pixels, not in rows/columns.

Comment: Yes, it is pixels. Rows and columns are *specific* to QTableView and that has mapping between pixel position and columns/rows. For example `QTableView::rowAt` or `QTableView::rowViewportPosition(int row)`. Qt's model/view involves quite a few classes and concepts. It is best to read (and re-read) documentation about it in detail. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html